# ExecutorService very slow with large for loop in java

Tags: java, for-loop, executorservice

i tried to do manipulations on files with threds pool but no luck, its very slow..

this is what i tried:

```
    int chunks = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    int iterations = listOfFiles.length;
    if(chunks > iterations)
        chunks = iterations;

    for(int i = 0; i < chunks; i++){
        final int from = iterations / chunks * i;
        final int to = iterations / chunks * (i + 1);
        service.submit(new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int j = from; j < to; j++) {
                    File curFile = listOfFiles[j];
                    ....
                }
            }
        });
    }

        service.shutdown();
        try {
            service.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
```

when:

```
iterations = 150,000;
chunks = 4;
```

Actually its doing 4 times each group. its look like :

```
file
file
file
file
------its stop for 2-3 seconds---
file
file
file
file
------its stop for 2-3 seconds---
file
file
file
file
------its stop for 2-3 seconds---
.......
```

How can i do it much more quickly without the stop of 2-3 seconds each group?

tnx a lot

Comment: `File curFile = listOfFiles[j]; ....` Whatever is causing the stops it's probably in the `....` part, which you haven't shown us.

Comment: While `Thread`s are `Runnable`, don't submit `new Thread()` to the executor. That's just bizzare. The Executor already has its own threads, they just need `Runnable`s to work on.

Comment: @malt its same performance with thread and runnable... i tried

Comment: @kfir that's because your current bottleneck is probably elsewhere, as markspace pointed out. That doesn't mean that submitting Threads into an executor is sane.

Comment: @markspace actually with iterations of 700 or lower like this its working perfectly and quickly without stoping...

Comment: So just post the relevant code that you left out with `....`. Then someone might be able to help you.

Comment: Tnx, all the time i thought my problem its in the threads pool, its really was in the .... code my problem solved!